# libGDX setCursorCatched and simple config bug

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to figure out some very odd behavior in libGDX right now. Take the following simple application code as an example.

```
package com.station40.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.station40.Station40;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.width = 800;
        config.height = 600;
        LwjglApplication app = new LwjglApplication(new Station40(), config);
        Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);
    }
}
```

Simple enough. I encounter 2 consistent problems with this though:

- When the cursor is actually "catched", invisible and impossible to move, the javaw process appears to freeze. The CPU usage sticks to 1 whole processor. Similar code to above stops executing normal frame updates with no other changes besides setCursorCatch(true) was called. What is happening here? Have I done something wrong?
- Annoyingly, when launched from Eclipse, the application *ignores* the config completely; every time I run an application it will open in a tiny window like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qclHI.png. The first time I ran this application, it opened fine at 800x600. Since then, it reverted (like all the other before it) to this tiny window. For reference, fullscreen completely fails: I get a resolution change but I see no window. My mouse is even caught.

Has anyone encountered these issues before? I've setup using the Gradle setup as described on the wiki. I've been using libGDX a long time and never had these issues until now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let this be a lesson to update ALL versions of a library. Or, better yet, keep only one copy! My old libGDX utility project was importing an older version of libGDX while new ones, using the Gradle system, imported the new ones. The two did not mesh well and caused all of the listed problems.

I moved the old utility project into a new Gradle-managed project and things are working better now.

For those wondering, this was because lwjgl expects a certain buffer of ints for window size to be in (top, bottom, left, right) order in one version and (top, left, bottom, right) order in another. I expect it disliked the resulting 0-height, negative-width window!